# How to display modal from bootstrap by checking cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie only when a button in the modal(bootstrap) is clicked. I have written the below code to set and get cookies but i am going somewhere wrong because the cookies are set automatically when the page is loaded and the modal is not displayed at all. I need to set it only when the button is clicked. I have no idea how the cookies are set when the modal does not even show up to click the #setcookie_btn. Any ideas where this code goes wrong ?

```
    $('#setcookie_btn').click(setCookie('{{user.get_username}}', true, 0.042));

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
            }
        }
            return "";
    }

    var cookie_val = getCookie('{{user.get_username}}');

    $(window).load(function() {

        if(cookie_val == false || "" ) {
            $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});    
        }

    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for binding `click` event is not correct. Actually it is calling the function `setcookie` instead of binding.

Change

```
$('#setcookie_btn').click(setCookie('{{user.get_username}}', true, 0.042));
```

To

```
$('#setcookie_btn').click(function()
{
 setCookie('{{user.get_username}}', true, 0.042)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is

```
 $('#setcookie_btn').click(setCookie('{{user.get_username}}', true, 0.042));
```

Basically you are not passing a function reference but in actual fact executing the function and passing the return value as the 'handler'. If you want to pass arguments to a function and assign as an handler, just use an anonymous function:

```
 $('#setcookie_btn').click(function() {
    setCookie('{{user.get_username}}', true, 0.042));
});
```

Also, not sure what you are checking for in your conditional?

```
if(cookie_val == false || "" ) {
     $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});    
}
```

Did you mean to check `cookie_val` to be false or an empty string? If so, it should be

```
if (cookie_val === false || cookie_val === '')
```